# Escape character for parameter in function of EL

Tags: jsf, el

I have this element in my page:

```
<p:panel header="Advies van de dienst aangemaakt op: #{of:formatDate(advies.aangemaaktOp, 'dd/MM/yyyy HHumm')}">
```

It renders to:

```
Advies van de dienst aangemaakt op: 30/03/2016 14357
```

It should be:

```
Advies van de dienst aangemaakt op: 30/03/2016 14u57
```

How do I achieve this? I know I should find a way to escape the 'u' character but since I am in a parameter of a function in an expression of EL, I cannot find a solution to do it.

Suggestion on the internet which doesn't work is using the tick '.
Tried also to escape with backslash but also no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is 'dd/MM/yyyy HH\'u\'mm'. I had to escape the tick itself.

Complete element:

```
<p:panel header="Advies van de dienst aangemaakt op: #{of:formatDate(advies.aangemaaktOp, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH\'u\'mm')}">
```